Оборудование и операционная система для домашнего сервера с БД, сайтом и облачным хранилищем
Возникло большое желание сделать свой домашний сервер, но т.к. я в этом полный новичок, то я пришёл сюда за советами. Этот пост скорее сборник вопросов и я рад, если Вы сможете на них ответить.

Какое оборудование выбирать для домашнего сервера?

На рынке сейчас существуют разные решения, поэтому мне нужен совет, что лучше выбрать
Из моих "хотелок" на сервере должно присутствовать:

СУБД(несколько небольших БД) для хранения данных для каких-нибудь своих приложений/сайтов. Данные включают: текстовые, различные медиаданные и т.п.
Свои сайты: интерфейс БД, интерфейс файлового хранилища, различные другие сайты
Файловое облачное хранилище для хранения личных файлов

Также было бы неплохо, если позволит железо, размещать простые хосты серверов для Minecraft,Satisfactory или иных проектов(это вообще не обязательно, просто как дополнительная нагрузка)
Из вариантов, я сам пришёл к варианту "Мини-ПК", т.к. по энергопотреблению они сравнительно нетребовательные(насколько мне известно), а производительность довольно хорошая. Я пришёл к этому варианту:

Портативный мини-ПК "Beelink MINI S N5095" с процессором Intel Jasper Lake Processor N5095  16гб оперативки и 1тб встроенной памяти. Хотя я думаю, что можно взять 256гб и купить два 1тб в RAID режиме, для сохранности данных, если это будет иметь смысл

Варианты с NAS-серверами, я так понял, рассматривать бессмысленно, т.к. они предназначены просто для хранения большого массива данных и в основном используются компаниями
Буду рад услышать ваше мнения и решения по этому вопросу

Операционная система

Я узнал, что есть решение Ubuntu Server, с различными доп. встройками как Apache2 для хостинга сервера и MySQL/PostrgreSQL
Думаю, что данного выбора вполне достаточно, но если Вы знаете какое-то более релевантное решение, то буду рад услышать

Вопрос по маршрутизции

Если у меня есть роутер, подключённый к основному, то достаточно ли мне иметь статический адрес для подключённого роутера?
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы!

Вы не можете задавать "Сборник вопросов" (тем более субъективных) на StackOverflow...

Какие вопросы лучше не задавать

Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать

@Chaos_Sower Да ну

@rotabor, а что?)

"Здравствуйте, меня зовут Весельчик У" (из Булычёва). Для начала план нормальный, действуйте. Достаточно иметь статический адрес на внешнем маршрутизаторе, и настроить на нём маршрут на сервер по портам.


Конечно, мини-ПК не очень подходит под сервера, если даже будет работать стабильно, то будет греться - большой минус компактных компьютеров. Если сервер небольшого масштаба (до 500 человек одновременно) - то можно. Моя лучшая рекомендация - собрать свой ПК на основе Ryzen Threadreaper или Epyc. Не обязательно брать дорогущие по 50-80, а то и 200 тыс. Можно обойтись и тем, что за 10-20, 32 ядра + 128 потоков - лучшее за свою цену, плюс герцовка большая для серверных процессоров. Что на счёт памяти - если, опять же сервер не рассчитан на много человек - то 2 ТБ вполне хватит (если конечно люди не станут хранить 10-часовые фильмы). Иначе стоит брать побольше. Вот мой список примерных соотношений количества человек на требуемые значения сервера:


30 чел. -  50-150 ГБ   / 6 ядер - 6-12 потоков      / 5К руб
100 чел. - 200-300 ГБ  / 8 ядер     - 8-16 потоков  / 7-8К руб
200 чел. - 400-1000 ГБ / 10-12 ядер - 10-24 потока  / 9-12К руб
500 чел. - 1-3 ТБ      / 10-14 ядер - 10-28 потоков / 14-20К руб
1К чел.  - 2-5 ТБ      / 12-16 ядер - 24-32 потока  / 25-50К руб
5К+ чел. - 10+ ТБ      / 16+ ядер   - 32+ потоков   / 60К+ руб


С этим согласен. Но если нужно раздвигать границы сервера - лучше взять Linux. Под него есть решения для серверов, но с ним всё будет труднее из-за его излишней гибкости - буквально любую настройку хостинга придётся писать самому.
Честно, не знаю. У меня хоть и был друг, который как-то умудрился сделать сервер через роутер, но он работал так нестабильно, обычная html-страница загружалась через раз. Возможно, передача интернета по воздуху - не очень хорошая идея. Я сам делал простым путём - кабель от интернета для компов - и всё работало. Но для этого нужно ещё покупать домен, место/ячейку в сети Интернет, а это бывает дорого.

Что-ж, на вопросы я ответил не очень, надеюсь, что-нибудь помогло.

Спасибо за разъяснение! Вы говорите об полноценном коммерческом сервере, оданко мне нужен просто сервер для семьи и для себя. Я не преследую цель выжимать из него мощности для большой аудитории. Вы называете какие-то слишком малые суммы для серверных процессоров, которые я не смог найти в интернете. Спасибо за Ваш ответ ещё раз!
